# What do we know about the features of Dark Matter?

Tags: visible-light, dark-matter, matter, states-of-matter, exotic-matter

In 2020, how much information have we got about this matter? I'm just curious.

Comment: have you looked at wikipedia?

Comment: every source and page repeats the same info. no, any update?

Comment: not to my knowledge. I haven't heard of any breakthroughs or new experiments.

Comment: The most important thing we know about it is that it doesn’t emit or absorb electromagnetic radiation, hence the name.